# Retrieving artist IDs from API -- processing them as long vs. int?

Tags: java, json, long-integer

Beginning programmer here, so bear with me!

I'm trying to retrieve some artist IDs from a music website's API. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
JSONObject jsonItem = (JSONObject) jsonResults.get(i);
System.out.println(jsonItem.get("id")); // Prints 22989
int currID = (Integer) jsonItem.get("id");
```

I'm trying to add multiple IDs into an int array, so I can process them later (hence the get(i)).

However, I get the following error when I run the above code:

> java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

What is the best way to handle something like this? Should I be attempting to cast everything to an int? Maybe handle different types of IDs, such as long's? Never really encountered a problem quite like this before.

Thanks!

Comment: `Long` and `Integer` are object types, not primitive data types.  You need to convert to the corresponding primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

```
int currID = (Integer) jsonItem.get("id");
```

Probably should read

```
long currID = (Long) jsonItem.get("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

From your error, I am assuming that the return value of jsonItem.get("id") is a java.lang.Long

Two ways

1) Preferred: store the id on your side as a long.

```
long currId = jsonItem.get("id");
```

2) I do not recommend following, you might end up getting ids that wont fit in an 'int'

```
int currId = jsonItem.get("id").intValue(); // DO NOT do this..
```

I just mentioned the second option to let you know of the API availability.